# LinqToDB with SQLite - reference properties are null

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, orm, linq2db

I have a few POCOs on a relatively simple domain model. One example looks like this:

```
[Table("Tag")]
public partial class Tag
{
    [PrimaryKey, NotNull    ] public string Name        { get; set; } // varchar(128)
    [Column,        Nullable] public string Description { get; set; } // text(2147483647)
    [Column,        Nullable] public string ParentID    { get; set; } // varchar(128)

    #region Associations

    /// <summary>
    /// FK_Tag_0_0
    /// </summary>
    [Association(ThisKey="ParentID", OtherKey="Name", CanBeNull=true)]
    public Tag Parent { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FK_TagObjects_0_0_BackReference
    /// </summary>
    [Association(ThisKey="Name", OtherKey="TagID", CanBeNull=true)]
    public List<TagObject> ObjectLinks { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FK_TagSynonyms_0_0_BackReference
    /// </summary>
    [Association(ThisKey="Name", OtherKey="TagID", CanBeNull=true)]
    public List<TagSynonym> SynonymLinks { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FK_Tag_0_0_BackReference
    /// </summary>
    [Association(ThisKey="Name", OtherKey="ParentID", CanBeNull=true)]
    public List<Tag> Children { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

The names of the FKs are weird, but I countered that by specifying `MemberName`s for them in the .tt file like the readme suggested.

The problem is that when I grab one of my tag objects, all of the association properties are null - the `ParentID` for the relevant tags are correct, it just doesn't seem to map that to the `Parent` *or* `Children` properties like I'd expect.

Have I done something wrong here? I've double-checked the database itself. The .tt looks like this:

```
NamespaceName = "MyProg.Models";
GenerateBackReferences   = true;
OneToManyAssociationType = "List<{0}>";

LoadSQLiteMetadata(@"C:\my\path", "my.db");

var k = GetFK("Tag", "FK_Tag_0_0");
k.MemberName = "Parent";
k.BackReference.MemberName = "Children";

GenerateModel();
```

Answer (score 4):

In linq2db associations define relations between tables. They help to build cross-table LINQ queries using association properties navigation instead of awkward (as for me) join syntax of LINQ.

If you need to fill association properties with data on select, you must specify it explicitly in your query using `LoadWith` method:

`var tagsWithChildren = db.Tags.LoadWith(t => t.Children).ToList();`

More examples could be found in tests here: https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/blob/master/Tests/Linq/Linq/LoadWithTests.cs

Comment: this requires [`LinqToDB.Common.Configuration.Linq.AllowMultipleQuery`](https://linq2db.github.io/api/LinqToDB.Common.Configuration.Linq.html#LinqToDB_Common_Configuration_Linq_AllowMultipleQuery) to be set to `true`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I overcame this issue - be aware I was using an Access db.

```
[Table(Name = "Customers")]
public class Customer
{
    [PrimaryKey, Identity]
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }

    [Column(Name="CompanyName"), NotNull]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Association(OtherKey = "CompanyID", ThisKey = "CompanyID", CanBeNull = true)]
    public Account Accounts { get; set; }
}
```

When the Association return type was an IEnumrable, the below usage was returning an IQueryable'<'IEnumerable'<'Account>>.

Usage:

```
using (var db = new DbMain())
{
     var q = from c in db.Customers
             select c.Accounts;

     System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(q.ToList()[0].AccountID);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm not sure, however, how that differs from my own setup. In either case, I decided to drop LinqToDB, but the information may be of use to someone else. :)